# jquery .css('display', 'block') not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying change the size select menu based on the gender that is chosen from the gender select menu. The male and female sizes work but the neutral is not. But the code should be almost exactly the same. Help please.

and this is my css which is just the basic displays of the different DIVS set to none so that I can update it to block whenever the specific gender is chosen.

```
#neutralSize {
    display: none;
}
#menSize {
    display: none;
}
#womenSize {
    display: none;
}
```

The correct male select shows up when male is chosen from the gender drop down. The correct female select shows up when female is chose also. But when neutral is chosen nothing happens.

```js
$('#costumeGender').on('change', function () {  
  var gender = $(this).val();

  if (gender === 'male') {
    $('#menSize').css('display', 'block');
    $('#womenSize').css('display', 'none');
    $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else if (gender === 'female') {
    $('#womenSize').css('display', 'block');
    $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'none');
    $('#menSize').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else if (gender === 'neutral') {
    $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'block');
    $('#menSize').css('display', 'none');
    $('#womenSize').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
#neutralSize {
  display: none;
}
#menSize {
  display: none;
}
#womenSize {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="costumeGender">Gender:</label>
<select name="costumeGender" id="costumeGender">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
</select>
<div id="menSize">
  <label for="costumeMen">Size:</label>
  <select name="costumeMen" id="costumeMen">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
    <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="womenSize">                              
  <label for="costumeWomen">Size:</label>
  <select name="costumeWomen" id="costumeWomen">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
    <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
    <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
  </select>
<div id="neutralSize">
  <label for="costumeNeutral">Size:</label>
  <select name="costumeNeutral" id="costumeNeutral">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
    <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to close the div element 
just add

```
   </div>
```

before

```
   <div id="neutralSize">
```

Answer (score 0):

It because you forgot to close `#womenSize` div, So your `#neutralSize` div was inside it. Just close it and it's working properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#costumeGender').on('change', function () {  //changes size dropdown in search based on gender
      var gender = $(this).val();

      if (gender === 'male') {
          $('#menSize').css('display', 'block');
          $('#womenSize').css('display', 'none');
          $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'none');
      }
      else if (gender === 'female') {
          $('#womenSize').css('display', 'block');
          $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'none');
          $('#menSize').css('display', 'none');
      }
      else if (gender === 'neutral') {
          $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'block');
          $('#menSize').css('display', 'none');
          $('#womenSize').css('display', 'none');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#neutralSize {
  display: none;
}
#menSize {
  display: none;
}
#womenSize {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="costumeGender">Gender:</label>
<select name="costumeGender" id="costumeGender">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
</select>
<div id="menSize">
    <label for="costumeMen">Size:</label>
    <select name="costumeMen" id="costumeMen">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
        <option value="small">Small</option>
        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="large">Large</option>
        <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
        <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="34">34</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="38">38</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="42">42</option>
        <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
        <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
        <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
        <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
        <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
        <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
        <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
        <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="womenSize">
    <label for="costumeWomen">Size:</label>
    <select name="costumeWomen" id="costumeWomen">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
        <option value="small">Small</option>
        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="large">Large</option>
        <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
        <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
        <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
        <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
        <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
        <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
        <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
        <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
        <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
        <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="neutralSize">
    <label for="costumeNeutral">Size:</label>
    <select name="costumeNeutral" id="costumeNeutral">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
        <option value="small">Small</option>
        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="large">Large</option>
        <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
        <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="34">34</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="38">38</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="42">42</option>
        <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
        <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
        <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
        <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
        <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
        <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
        <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
        <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
        <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check. You forget to close`<div id="womenSize">` div.

```js
$('#costumeGender').on('change', function () {  
  var gender = $(this).val();

  if (gender === 'male') {
    $('#menSize').css('display', 'block');
    $('#womenSize').css('display', 'none');
    $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else if (gender === 'female') {
    $('#womenSize').css('display', 'block');
    $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'none');
    $('#menSize').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else if (gender === 'neutral') {
    $('#neutralSize').css('display', 'block');
    $('#menSize').css('display', 'none');
    $('#womenSize').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
#neutralSize {
  display: none;
}
#menSize {
  display: none;
}
#womenSize {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="costumeGender">Gender:</label>
<select name="costumeGender" id="costumeGender">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
</select>
<div id="menSize">
  <label for="costumeMen">Size:</label>
  <select name="costumeMen" id="costumeMen">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
    <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="womenSize">                              
  <label for="costumeWomen">Size:</label>
  <select name="costumeWomen" id="costumeWomen">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
    <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
    <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="neutralSize">
  <label for="costumeNeutral">Size:</label>
  <select name="costumeNeutral" id="costumeNeutral">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="xsmall">Extra Small</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="xlarge">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="5">5 Shoe</option>
    <option value="5half">5 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6">6 Shoe</option>
    <option value="6half">6 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7">7 Shoe</option>
    <option value="7half">7 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8">8 Shoe</option>
    <option value="8half">8 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9">9 Shoe</option>
    <option value="9half">9 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10">10 Shoe</option>
    <option value="10half">10 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11">11 Shoe</option>
    <option value="11half">11 1/2 Shoe</option>
    <option value="12">12 Shoe</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
$('#ID').show(); //for display:block
```

and

```
$('#ID').hide(); //for display:none
```